# Why isn't this object being passed by reference when assigning something else to it?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

I know that in JS, objects are passed by reference, for example:

```
function test(obj) {
    obj.name = 'new name';
}

var my_obj = { name: 'foo' };
test(my_obj);
alert(my_obj.name); // new name
```

But why doesn't the below work:

```
function test(obj) {
    obj = {};
}

var my_obj = { name: 'foo' };
test(my_obj);
alert(my_obj.name); // foo
```

I have set the object to `{}` (empty) but it still says `foo`.

Can any one explain the logic behind this?

Comment: That's because objects are not passed by reference ;)

Comment: @delnan But there are. See how `currentObject` changes `$scope.countries` -> http://jsfiddle.net/ay1wpr5L/2/

Comment: @Imray That's not pass by reference, as explained by multiple answers below.

Comment: Freaking javascript. I love it and hate it all at the same time...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you are familiar with pointers, that's an analogy you can take. You're actually passing a pointer, so `obj.someProperty` would dereference to that property and actually override that, while merely overriding `obj` would kill off the pointer and not overwrite the object.

Comment: +1 - nicely done, and clearer than my answer (assuming OP knows about pointers)

Comment: @AdamRackis I +1'd your answer because it uses the JS terminology and brought above analogy to mind ; )

Comment: Thanks this one clarified it :)

Comment: Why didn't I find this answer when I searched for this last week!? This finally answered my question as well, many thanks!

Comment: Good to remember at this point is that when one declares a function with some param (like obj here) that obj is kind of new thing. It's like saying:  
`var obj; // undefined`  
inside that function. So if we are doing some assignments, we're actually altering local variable inside the function and we are breaking the "reference" (pointer).

Answer (score 30):

Because JavaScript actually passes objects by pass-by-**copy**-reference.

When you pass `my_obj` into your `test` function, a **copy** of a reference to that object is passed in.  As a result, when you re-assign the object in `test`, you're really only re-assigning a *copy of* a reference to the original object; your original `my_obj` remains un-changed.

Comment: If it is copy, then it why does it work in first example i have posted ? In my first example also then it should remain un-touched ?

Comment: @Dev555 - it's a copy of a **reference to** the object - I edited to be more clear.  In your first case, obj is a copy of a reference that points to your real object.  Adding a property will work fine.  If I were there in person I could draw some pictures of boxes with arrows that I think would help a lot :)

Comment: So how to initialize objects? Initially i had this `instance.initGrid($(instance.mainEntityContainer), instance.mainEntityList);
instance.initGrid($(instance.dependantEntityContainer), instance.dependantEntityList);`, I had to transform this to the following: `instance.mainEntityList = instance.initGrid($(instance.mainEntityContainer));
instance.dependantEntityList = instance.initGrid($(instance.dependantEntityContainer));` Still I wonder how to "free memory" from previous initializations. Whether I just have to make instance.dependantEntityList = null somewhere? I have "= new ..." inside.

Answer (score 26):

Because you are overwriting the reference, not the object.

```
// Create a new object and assign a reference to it
// to the variable my_obj
var my_obj = { name: 'foo' };

// Pass the reference to the test function
test(my_obj);

// Assign the reference to a variable called obj
// (since that is the first argument)
function test(obj) {
// Create a new (empty) object and assign a reference to it to obj
// This replaces the existing REFERENCE
    obj = {};
}
// my_obj still has a reference to the original object, 
// because my_obj wasn't overwritten
alert(my_obj.name); // foo
```

Comment: You are overwriting the copy of the reference, not the reference. If you would overwrite the reference itself, everything would be fine.

Comment: So how would you overwrite `my_obj` if you wanted to?

Comment: @CodyBugstein Wrap it in another object. Another answer on this question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452001/841830, shows this, along with some other possible approaches.  Or, if you don't like any of those approaches, I think the answer is basically: you can't overwrite `my_obj`.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript lacks support for passing by reference (although objects are passed by reference and the reference is maintained as long as it is not overwrited with assignment eg. using `=`), but you can imitate `ref` keyword of C# using the following technique:

```
function test(obj) {
  obj.Value = {};
  //obj.Value = {name:"changed"};
}

var my_obj = { name: 'foo' };

(function ()
{
  my_obj = {Value: my_obj};
  var $return = test(my_obj);
  my_obj = my_obj.Value;
  return $return;
}).call(this);

alert(my_obj.name); // undefined, as expected
                    // In the question this returns "foo" because
                    // assignment causes dereference
```

Of course you can use globals and call function without arguments, in which case the references are not missed like this:

```
var obj = { name: 'foo' };
function test() {
    obj = {};
}
test();
alert(obj.name); // undefined
```

If you have all your code in closure, then things are simpler and above like globals doesn't pollute global namespace:

```
(function(){
    var obj = { name: 'foo' };
    function test() {
        obj = {};
    }
    test();
    alert(obj.name); // undefined
}).call(this);
```

The above "globals inside closure" -technique is nice if you have to port to Javascript some C# code which has `ref` arguments. Eg. The following C# code:

```
void MainLoop()
{
   // ...
   MyStruct pt1 = CreateMyStruct(1);
   MyStruct pt2 = CreateMyStruct(2);
   SwapPoints(ref pt1, ref pt2);
   // ...
}
void SwapPoints(ref MyStruct pt1, ref MyStruct pt2)
{
    MyStruct tmp = pt1;
    pt1 = pt2;
    pt2 = tmp;
}
```

could be ported to Javascript using something like:

```
(function(){
    var pt1, pt2;
    function CreateMyStruct(myvar)
    {
      return {"myvar":myvar}  
    }
    function MainLoop()
    {
       // ...
       pt1 = CreateMyStruct(1);
       pt2 = CreateMyStruct(2);
       console.log("ORIG:",pt1,pt2); 
       SwapPoints(); 
       console.log("SWAPPED:",pt1,pt2);
       // ...
    }
    function SwapPoints()
    {
        var tmp = pt1;
        pt1 = pt2;
        pt2 = tmp;
    }
    MainLoop();

}).call(this);
```

or if it's essential to use local variables and function arguments, then solution can be based on the first example of my answer like this:

```
(function(){
    function CreateMyStruct(myvar)
    {
      return {"myvar":myvar}  
    }
    function MainLoop()
    {
      // ...
      var pt1 = CreateMyStruct(1);
      var pt2 = CreateMyStruct(2);
      console.log("ORIG:",pt1,pt2); 

      (function ()
      {
        pt1 = {Value: pt1};
        pt2 = {Value: pt2};
        var $return = SwapPoints(pt1, pt2);
        pt1 = pt1.Value;
        pt2 = pt2.Value;
        return $return;
      }).call(this);

      console.log("SWAPPED:",pt1,pt2);
      // ...
    }
    function SwapPoints(pt1, pt2)
    {
      var tmp = pt1.Value;
      pt1.Value = pt2.Value;
      pt2.Value = tmp;
    }
    MainLoop();
}).call(this);
```

Really have to say that Javascript lacks much when it has not native `ref`! The code would be much simpler.