# JavaScript object behavior

Tags: javascript, object

I do not get stumped often but I am just at a loss of words right now.

Using Chrome 37.0.2062.120 m

Can someone explain to me why my `console.log();` is reporting these results?

**JS code**

```
var some_obj = {min:1};

var another_obj = {};

console.log(some_obj);

another_obj['sometarget'] = some_obj; // <- What is this sorcery?!?!?
another_obj['sometarget']['required'] = true;

console.log(some_obj);
```

**console.log() output**

```
Object {min: 1}
Object {min: 1, required: true}
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/qrnaw7j2/1/

Comment: What part of that result do you not expect? What's the surprise that has you stumped?

Comment: Searching would have found you a few hundred duplicates, here's one -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437981/object-pass-by-reference**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects in javascript are shared via reference.

So `some_obj` and `another_obj['sometarget']` point to the same place in memory.

When you set `['required'] = true;` in any of them, they will both get updated.

Comment: Objects in javascript are not passed by reference !

Comment: The pointers to objects are not, but the objects per se are, because they share the same place in memory - they actualy 'point' to the same object. So I guess it depends on the notation :)

Comment: It's generally referred to as "copy of a reference" or "reference-like", javascript doesn't have pointers, nor does it pass by true reference.

Comment: Thanks Luan Nico! @adeneo The answer was explained in plain English and while there is argument over proper terminology of pass-by-whatever, Luan's `So some_obj and another_obj['sometarget'] point to the same place in memory.` remark is self-explanatory.