# Javascript navigation to nested JSON object not working when modifying whole object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to grammatically follow a path inside a JSON object, and replace the object with a blank one.

I'm using this method to reach the object desired, and I can verfiy that the object is reached.

```
$scope.path = "countries.canada.territories.yukon";
$scope.remove = function () {
    var pathInArrayForm = $scope.path.split('.');
    currentObject = $scope.countries;
    for (var i = 0; i < pathInArrayForm.length; i++){
        currentObject = currentObject[pathInArrayForm[i]];
    }
    currentObject.capital = "Montreal";
}
```

However, when I try to replace the object with a blank one, via

```
currentObject = {};
```

Nothing happens. It doesn't change anything! When I use:

```
currentObject.capital = "Montreal"
```

it works, but if I just use the object plain, nothing happens.

Please see my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ay1wpr5L/2/

**My question is**, how can I replace an object nested inside other JSON objects, with a blank `{}`?

Comment: Where's the angularjs tag?????????????????????

Comment: I've re-tagged your question. This isn't about JSON, it's not about passing by reference and it's not a "json path" (what's that? :D). It's just about AngularJS binding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't this object being passed by reference when assigning something else to it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437981/why-isnt-this-object-being-passed-by-reference-when-assigning-something-else-to)

Answer (score 0):

Objects are not passed by reference in JS. Read more about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437981/why-isnt-this-object-being-passed-by-reference-when-assigning-something-else-to) in another question on SO. The best answer I saw was by [Alexander Varwijk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576060/alexander-varwijk) and he said this:

> If you are familiar with pointers, that's an analogy you can take.
>   You're actually passing a pointer, so `obj.someProperty` would
>   dereference to that property and actually override that, while merely
>   overriding obj would kill off the pointer and not overwrite the
>   object.

To solve your question, just declare the `currentObject` to `$scope.countries` like such          `$scope.countries = currentObject;`

Comment: But `$scope.countries = currentObject;` would replace the whole JSON of countries with just the object for `yukon`. That would be bad

Comment: @Imray, then I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you explain some more?