# Parameter Passing: In and Out

Tags: javascript

Consider:

> Primitive data types are passed by value in JavaScript. This means
>   that a copy is effectively made of a variable when it is passed to a
>   function, so any manipulation local to the function leaves the
>   original variables untouched.

```
function fiddle(arg1) {
      arg1 = "Fiddled with";
      console.log("In function fiddle str = "+arg1+"<br>");
}
var str = "Original Value";
console.log("Before function call str = "+str+"<br>");
fiddle(str);
console.log("After function call str ="+str+"<br>");
```

[image]

***EASY***

> composite types such as arrays and objects if used, they are passed
>   by reference rather than value

Consider the following modification
of the previous fiddle() function:

```
function fiddle(arg1) {
       arg1[0] = "Fiddled with";
       console.log("In function fiddle arg1 = "+arg1+"<br>");
}
var arr = ["Original", " Original ", " Original "];
console.log("Before function call arr = "+arr+"<br>");
fiddle(arr);
console.log("After function call arr ="+arr+"<br>");
```

[image]

***FINE till here***

From here I find myself really confused,

```
function fiddle(arg1) {
      arg1 = ["Blasted!","Blasted!"];
      console.log("In function fiddle arg1 = "+arg1+"<br>");
}
var arr = ["Original", " Original ", " Original "];
console.log("Before function call arr = "+arr+"<br>");
fiddle(arr);
console.log("After function call arr ="+arr+"<br>"); // Why this hasn't changed?
```

[image]

Any suggestion? And will it be OK to say

> composite types such as arrays and objects if used, they are passed
>       by reference rather than value

in this case too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't this object being passed by reference when assigning something else to it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437981/why-isnt-this-object-being-passed-by-reference-when-assigning-something-else-to)

Comment: If you do `arg1.push("Blasted!","Blasted!");` then changes are done to the original, but you're creating a new array inside fiddle by using `arg1 = []`.

Comment: Assigning to a name is not the same as mutating the object that name happens to refer to. The former only changes the name binding. The latter the object.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty clear, inside `fiddle` you're overwriting the reference to `arr` with an array you created on the spot. You never touched `arr` itself through its reference, just the reference, so once you're outside again, `arr` is still the original array.

Comment: @Blindly: I Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the bracket notation (for arrays) or the dot notation (for objects) allows you to mutate objects within an array/object, which will propagate up and outwards the scope of the function as they are passed by reference, even though the "parent" object is passed by value. This feature is known as [**call-by-sharing**, as addressed in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/395910). In short:

- Everything is passed by value,  *but*...
- Objects within the "everything" (if exists, i.e. for arrays and objects) is passed by reference

If you want to modify `arr` outside of the scope of the `fiddle()` function, you will have to return it, i.e.: `return arr1;` and then assign `arr = fiddle(arg1[,arg2,...])`, like as follow:

```js
function fiddle(arg1) {
  arg1 = ["Blasted!","Blasted!"];
  $('body').append("In function fiddle arg1 = "+arg1+"<br>");
  return arg1;
}
var arr = ["Original", " Original ", " Original "];
$('body').append("Before function call arr = "+arr+"<br>");
arr = fiddle(arr);
$('body').append("After function call arr ="+arr+"<br>"); // Why this hasn't changed?
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Terry.