# object literal dynamic key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was following the node functional programing tutorial in [here](https://github.com/timoxley/functional-javascript-workshop), but when I  tried implement my code for lesson # 12 as follow

```
function Spy(target, method) {
  var store={};
  var self=this;
  var copy=target[method];
  store[target[method]]=0;
  console.log(store);
  console.log(store[target[method]]);
    target[method]=function(){
        store[target[method]]+=1;
      return copy.apply(this,arguments);
    };
  
  return {count:store[target[method]]}; 
}

var spy = Spy(console, 'error');

console.error('calling console.error');
console.error('calling console.error');
console.error('calling console.error');

console.log(spy.count);
```

I got the `console.log(store)` within Spy return an object containing a  function. Also, the final return `return {count:store[target[method]]};` from Spy return undefined. Can anyone please explain the reasons behind these two? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after setting `store[target[method]]=0;` you are setting `target[method]` to be equal to a function, this messes up the value of `store[target[method]]` and makes it undefined. Looks like you will want to use your `copy` value on the `return`:

```
return {count:store[copy]};
```

Although that doesn't help that the `count` will still be `0` in this case. This is because you are returning an object in `Spy` directly `{prop: value, ...}`, as such you cannot really modify it within the `Spy` function. Although to get around that define the object `{count:store[copy]}` as a variable within your constructor (`var returnObj = {count:store[copy]};`), then return that variable: `return returnObj`. Now you can update `returnObj.count` inside `[target[method]]`.

This works because `Object`'s in JavaScript are passed-by-reference.

```js
function Spy(target, method) {
  var store={};
  var self=this;
  var copy=target[method];
  store[target[method]]=0;
  var returnObj = {count:store[copy]};

    target[method]=function(){
        returnObj.count+=1;
        return copy.apply(this,arguments);
    };

  return returnObj; 
}

var spy = Spy(console, 'error');

console.error('calling console.error');
console.error('calling console.error');
console.error('calling console.error');

console.log(spy.count);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the solution :}

Comment: Just want to add a follow up, after I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437981/why-isnt-this-object-being-passed-by-reference-when-assigning-something-else-to is it truth such that passing object in JS should be more like a pass by pointer scenario in C++ than passing reference in C++, since the pointer can be override?

Comment: @seanh I would still consider it pass-by-reference since that's how it's functionality working, but rather implemented slightly different. It's passed by [*"copy of a reference"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference). Basically it passes by value of the reference, so it's implemented as pass-by-value but functionality acts as if it's pass-by-reference. [The value being passed in this case is the reference itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I am really appreciate you help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to explain the stuff with the additional logs i have put in your code

```
function Spy(target, method) {
  var store={};
  var self=this;
  var copy=target[method];  // #0.1
  store[target[method]]=0; //  #0.2
  console.log('Before :: store', store); // #1
  console.log('Before :: target[method]', target[method]); // #2

  target[method]=function(){
      store[target[method]]+=1;
      return copy.apply(this,arguments);
  }; // #3

  console.log('After :: store', store);  // #4
  console.log('After :: target[method]', target[method]);  // #5
  return {count:store[target[method]]}; // #6
}

var spy = Spy(console, 'error');
console.log(spy.count);
```

`target[method]` is a function which looks something like `function () { [native code] }` (replace native code with some code written in js lib).

At `0.2` you are making this function (in stringified form) a key of `store` object and assigning its value to `0`.
So, your store object looks something like

```
`Before :: store { 'function () { [native code] }': 0 }`
```

at `#1` and `target[method]` is a native function at `#2`.

Now at `#3` you are assigning `target[method]` a new function, so now onwards `target[method]` will refer to your new function.

So, at `#4` your store objects remains same. (Since key is a stringified value of function.) which is

```
`After :: store { 'function () { [native code] }': 0 }`
```

but since you made assignment in `#3`, so your `target[method]` value has changed to new function which is

```
After :: target[method] function (){
      store[target[method]]+=1;
      return copy.apply(this,arguments);
  }
```

Now at `#6` you are trying to fetch a key which from store object which does not exists in `store` object, so that is why it `returns undefined` and store value of count to `undefined`

Comment: Thank you very much, this totally makes sense now :) How about the native code comes from, it doesn't look like it is something that pass in by the caller of Spy ?

Comment: native code comes from javascript engine. Your code runs on top of Js Engine which implements ECMA specs. In this implementation their is an object called `console` which has `error` function. This error function has some implementation in it as well, and `in our logs native code` refers to `console.error()`'s implementation.